# Jquery date picker don't work after remove input attribute

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, date, datepicker, twitter-bootstrap-3

this is my [Jsfiddle code](http://jsfiddle.net/79jFB/), I have an input text with date picker; when this input is readonly i don't show a popup calendar. Where i clicked button remove readonly attribut but the popup calendar don't show again. What's wrong?

HTML:

```
<input type="text" name="data_contratto" id="data_contratto" class="form-control                         datamask datamask datapick" value="01/06/2013" readonly>
<button class="btneditlog btn btn-default" type="button" data-edit="daticontratto"><span class="fa fa-edit"></span></button>
```

JS:

```
$('.datapick' ).datepicker({ 
        dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy",
        beforeShow: function (input, inst) {
         if ($(input).prop("readonly")) {
                 inst.dpDiv = $('<div style="display: none;"></div>');
              }    
        }});

$('.btneditlog').click(function(e){
   $('#data_contratto').removeAttr("readonly"); 
    });
```

Thank's in Advanced. Marco.

Comment: Do you want to show datepcicker when you click on the button?

Answer (score 1):

If I understood you correctly, there is an easy fix by returning false if the input is infact readonly:

```
$('.datapick' ).datepicker({ 
    dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy",
    beforeShow: function (input, inst) {
     if ($(input).prop("readonly")) {
            return false;
          }    
}});
```

Updated fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/79jFB/1/

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies in

```
inst.dpDiv = $('<div style="display: none;"></div>');
```

which hides the `<div>` the datepicker plugin provides.

The work around for this can be, re-initializing the datepicker on button click.

```
$('.btneditlog').click(function(e){
    $('#data_contratto').removeAttr("readonly");
    $('.datapick').datepicker('destroy').datepicker()
});
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/79jFB/2/)**

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue might be that you are removing the attribute, but not actually reseting the property, which is what your beforeShow is looking at. On the button click try:

```
$('.btneditlog').click(function(e){
    $('#data_contratto').prop("readonly", false); 
});
```

Comment: Although look like you are rewriting the inst.dpDiv in your function, so when it gets called after being destroyed it will load as your re-written empty div.